# Case insensitive search in bootstrap table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to find and highlight the matching text in a bootstrap table.

Here is the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/74/

**HTML**

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <thead>
        <tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th></tr>    
    </thead>
    <tbody id='UserInfoTableBody'>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>UserName 1</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>2</td><td>UserName 2</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>3</td><td>UserName 1</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>4</td><td>UserName 3</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>5</td><td>UserName 2</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>6</td><td>UserName 2</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>7</td><td>UserName 1</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>8</td><td>UserName 1</td></tr>  
        <tr><td>9</td><td>username 2</td></tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
HighlightMatches();

function HighlightMatches(){

var textToMatch = 'UserName 2';

$('.match').replaceWith(function () {
    return this.innerText;
  });     

$('#UserInfoTableBody td').each(function (i, tdContent) {
    var $td = $(tdContent);
    $td.html($td.html().
             split(textToMatch).
             join('<span class="match">' + textToMatch + '</span>'));
});
```

}

**CSS**

```
.match{background-color:yellow;}
```

**Problem:**

The current search is case-sensitive and I want it to be case-insensitive. In the code above, I am trying to search 'UserName 2' but it is missing the value in last row (username 2).

I tried to use contains but in that case, I am not sure how to highlight the text. Any help is appreciated.

**Expectation**

Highlight only the matching text. 
Should work for,

```
var textToMatch = '2';
var textToMatch = 'User';
var textToMatch = 'user';
```

Comment: But I'm wondering what are you doing at this line: $('.match').replaceWith ...

Comment: @sylvain1264,  it may not be useful here... but the actual functionality is, the value to textToMatch is dynamic and I want to remove the previous highlights before performing a new search.

Comment: @downvoter, may I know the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
HighlightMatches();

function HighlightMatches(){

    var textToMatch = 'username';

    $('.match').replaceWith(function () {
        return this.innerText;
      });     

    $('#UserInfoTableBody td:odd').each(function (i, tdContent) {
        var $td = $(tdContent);
        var pos = $td.html().toLowerCase().search(textToMatch);
        var len = textToMatch.length;
        if(pos != -1 ){
            var match = $td.html().substring(pos, len+pos);
            var splitted = $td.html().split(match);
            $td.html(splitted[0] + '<span class="match">' + match + '</span>' + splitted[1]);
        }
    });
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/87/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, the above logic will fail if you replace var textToMatch = 'username'. (partial search of the td text)

Comment: @sylvain1264, thanks for updating your solution. But, I need to highlight only the matching text.. not the entire text in td. If you look at my fiddler, replace var textToMatch = '2' and it will highlight only the matching text.

Comment: You need to be specific what kind of features you are trying to achieve in your question clearly. By adding on new requests in your comments repeatedly makes you a help vampire.

Comment: @sylvain1264, seems to be working now... +1 from me be answering patiently :)

Comment: ur welcome, u can also add ":odd" to the selector to prevent highlight ranking.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
"containsIN": function(elem, i, match, array) {
return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || "").toLowerCase().indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
}
});

HighlightMatches();

function HighlightMatches(){

    var textToMatch = 'UserName 2';

    $('.match').replaceWith(function () {
        return this.innerText;
      });     

    $('#UserInfoTableBody td').each(function (i, tdContent) {
         $('td:containsIN("'+textToMatch+'")').html('<span class="match">' + textToMatch + '</span>');
    });
}
```

you can try this.
https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/85/

Comment: I am sorry, this is not I am looking for.  I need to highlight only the matching text.. not the entire text in td. If you look at my fiddler, replace var textToMatch = '2' and it will highlight only the matching text.

Comment: if I use var textToMatch = '2', the other text in td disappears... :( All I want is to highlight only the matching text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `toLowerCase()`.

this function characters converted to lowercase. use this function for `textToMatch` and `td`

Good luck